# CSS animation forwards and then backwards

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a CSS animation that when the user clicks the burger menu it transforms to an x (step 1), then when the user clicks it again it animates back to the burger menu (step 2).

Step 1 works but I don’t know how to reverse the animation.
Thanks for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/aX6Cf/

HTML

```
<a id="mobile-menu">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-plus {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotate-minus {
  from {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);

  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes transition-1 {
  from {
    top: -6;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;

  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes transition-2 {
  from {
    bottom: -6;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;

  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
  }
} 


body {
    margin: 20px;
}

#mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer; 
  width: 30px;
  padding: 6px 30px 9px 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mobile-menu span, 
#mobile-menu span:before, 
#mobile-menu span:after {
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

#mobile-menu span:before {
  top: -6px; 
}

#mobile-menu span:after {
  bottom: -6px;
}

#mobile-menu.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#mobile-menu.active span:before {
-webkit-animation: rotate-plus .05s ease-out .1s forwards,
                   transition-1 .05s ease-out forwards;  
        animation: rotate-plus .05s ease-out .1s forwards,
                   transition-1 .05s ease-out forwards; 
}

#mobile-menu.active span:after {
-webkit-animation: rotate-minus .05s ease-out .1s forwards, 
                   transition-2 .05s ease-out forwards;
        animation: rotate-minus .05s ease-out .1s forwards, 
                   transition-2 .05s ease-out forwards;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#mobile-menu").click(function(){
    $("#mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Use transitions, not an animation

Comment: Sometimes these things can be cumbersome (if possible at all) to do with CSS. In this particular case, I'd just use GSAP http://jsfiddle.net/aX6Cf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take back what I said in my comment above. Looks like it *is* possible to do this with plain CSS, after all... The trick is to use transition delays properly.

**HTML**

```
<a id="mobile-menu">
   <span></span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 20px;
}

#mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 30px;
    padding: 6px 30px 9px 0; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mobile-menu span, 
#mobile-menu span:before, 
#mobile-menu span:after {
    height: 3px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

#mobile-menu span {
    transition: background-color .3s ease .3s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease .3s;
}

#mobile-menu span:before {
    top: -6px;
    transition: top .2s ease .2s, transform .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top .2s ease .2s, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
}

#mobile-menu span:after {
    bottom: -6px;
    transition: bottom .2s ease .2s, transform .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: bottom .2s ease .2s, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
}

#mobile-menu.active span {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

#mobile-menu.active span:before {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: top .2s ease .1s, transform .2s ease .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .2s ease .1s, -webkit-transform .2s ease .3s;
}

#mobile-menu.active span:after {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: bottom .2s ease .1s, transform .2s ease .3s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom .2s ease .1s, -webkit-transform .2s ease .3s;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#mobile-menu").click(function(){
        $("#mobile-menu").toggleClass("active");
    });
})
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aX6Cf/2/)

Comment: Nice! I didn’t know that it is possible to use `transform` within the `transition` property and taking advantage of the delay property. Thanks very much! May I ask why the transition isn’t fired on load?

Comment: A transition only specifies *how* a property change occurs, not *when* this should happen (i.e. transitions can't trigger property changes by themselves). It doesn't really make sense to trigger a transition when the initial property values are set, because (1) you don't have a 'from' part to interpolate from and (2) the only sensible default choice IMO would be that 'from' part == 'to' part == initial values, which is kind of moot. Note though that it *is* possible to trigger a transition on (or shortly after) load if this is the desired behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/aX6Cf/5/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh9sj/) which I tweaked a little bit (to much your code) from the [original one in this awesome Codepen](http://codepen.io/SperWalas/pen/Fzrnk).

**HTML**

```
<a id="mobile-menu" href="#">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a#mobile-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a#mobile-menu span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  color:#252525;
  font:bold 14px/.4 Helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent:-55px;
  background: #252525;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}
a#mobile-menu span::before, a#mobile-menu span::after {
  content:'';
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #252525;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  transition:all .2s ease-out;
}
a#mobile-menu span::before {
  top: -7px;
}
a#mobile-menu span::after {
  bottom: -7px;
}
a#mobile-menu.active span {
    background: #fff;
}
a#mobile-menu.active span::before {
  top:0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
       -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
          transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
a#mobile-menu.active span::after {
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
       -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

a#mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-9px;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-9px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**As I said all credit goes [to this codepen](http://codepen.io/SperWalas/pen/Fzrnk)**

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but it’s important that the rotation starts after the upper and lower lines moved to the middle.